# Can not connect to SQL Server database file from C# project if running in release mode

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

Why can I not connect to my `.mdf` database file if running in release mode, but in debug mode, there's no problem?

I using configuration file

```
<connectionStrings>       
    <add name="connections"   
         connectionString="Data Source=.\; attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\DataPesta.mdf;Initial Catalog=DataPesta;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"                  
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I try build to .exe using advance installer and choose debug project the problem like release running problem.

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Database 'C:\Users\tomit\Pictures\MessagingApp\MessagingApp\bin\Debug\DataPesta.mdf' already exists. Choose a different database name.
>
> Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\tomit\Pictures\MessagingApp\MessagingApp\bin\Release\DataPesta.mdf' as database 'DataPesta'.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Your exception is giving two differents paths.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, I just using 1 path in config

Comment: He means `\bin\Debug` is different from `bin\Release`

Comment: ok thks, i get that :D